# Subgraph $K_5$ (or $K_{3,3}$)

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, forbidden-subgraphs

I'm having trouble with the two graphs below. Graph appears like it will have a $K_5$, however, I can't connect the vertices properly. How do these graphs have a $K_5$ (or $K_{3,3}$)?

[image: graph]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2239349/graph-theory-subgraph-k3-3-or-k5

Comment: To be clear, if you are looking to prove the graph is not planar, you do not show that it has *a subgraph* that is $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$... you show that it has a subgraph that is $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ *or has a subgraph that is a subdivision of one of those*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph has a $K_{3,3}$ minor.  The vertices used will be labeled either blue or red indicating which part they come from, and edges utilized will be pictured red.

[image]

Note in particular how the edge in the $K_{3,3}$ which connects the middle-left vertex to the middle-right is made up of two edges in the original graph.